# Node Js Meme generation error: File does not exist

Tags: javascript, node.js

Total nodejs newbie here. I am using [meme-maker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/meme-maker) package to generate meme. However I want to create meme with image from url

```
var fileName = 'https://imgflip.com/s/meme/Futurama-Fry.jpg';
var memeMaker = require('meme-maker')

var options = {
  image: fileName,         // Required
  outfile: 'meme.png',  // Required
  topText: 'top',            // Required
  bottomText: 'bottom',           // Optional
}

memeMaker(options, function(err) {
  if(err) throw new Error(err)
  console.log('Image saved: ')
});
```

However I get error: Error: File does not exist: https://imgflip.com/s/meme/Futurama-Fry.jpg

How to read file from url and make meme?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you go read the documentation of [meme-maker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/meme-maker) you will see that it only supports local images and not URL's.

You will need to download the image first then use the local address. Go have a look at [request](https://github.com/request/request)

Answer (score 0):

That library does not look like it supports URLs. The `image` param presumably takes a file path on the local system. If you want to use the URL to make a meme, you will have to:

1. Download that image from the URL using AJAX or something similar, store it to a file on the disk and get it's local path.
2. Pass the local file path of the file to the library
3. Get the generated meme path (and enable download if needed) and do clean up like deleting the old image, for example